# How does .then pass the results of the invoking function to its promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I've gone through a few questions similar to this but haven't been able to find one for this specific bit I'm having trouble understanding. I'll insert the code, what it outputs, what I'm having trouble understanding, and maybe someone can point out what I'm missing:

```
async function add(x, y) {
 return x + y
}

add(1,2).then((result) => {
 console.log(result)
})

3
```

So far I know that async functions in JS will always return a promise, but my understanding of promises is that they take two function callbacks as parameters, one for when the promise resolves and the other for when it encounters an error. How does the compiler know to pass the result from the add function here into the resolve callback of the returned promise? Is it just assumed when .then is invoked that the first parameter of the returned promise's resolve callback will be the return value of the invoking function?

Comment: *but my understanding of promises is that they take two function callbacks as parameters, one for when the promise resolves and the other for when it encounters an error* This is only true for the Promise constructor, nothing else

Comment: Suggested read about `Promise`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I would recommend reading up on promises. I personally would recommend [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought the OP was talking about `.then()` taking two callbacks as parameters, one for when the promise fulfills and the other when it rejects…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far I know that async functions in JS will always return a promise, but my understanding of promises is that they take two function callbacks as parameters, one for when the promise resolves and the other for when it encounters an error.

This is the case for the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor. It takes a resolve and a reject function, one of which (resolve) you call with the value to resolve the promise with, and the other (reject) you call with the error to throw. However, async functions are slightly different. When they return a value, they actually return a promise that **resolves** to the value that they return. If there is an error, then it **rejects** it and throws a promise error. Also, [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) will always handle the value the promise resolves, and [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) will always handle the error that the promise rejects.

Comment: Thank you. This (and the comments like this), along with the javascript.info page on Promises helped make the issue clear. This line:

promise.then(
  function(result) { /* handle a successful result */ },
  function(error) { /* handle an error */ }
);

made it click.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Just a quick note, it is considered better to only provide one function (the function for a successful promise) to `.then`, and to provide the error handling function to `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with how the [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (the "[resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)" function) works, then the code snippet below could be helpful.

```js
async function add(x, y) {
 return x + y
}

add(1,2).then((result) => {
 console.log(result)
})

//can be written as

function add2 (x,y){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   resolve(x+y);
  })
}

add2(1,2).then((result) => {
 console.log(result)
})
```